# How to image upload into database using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload an image into the database but unfortunately it is not inserting an image into the database. How can I fix it?

Database table: https://ibb.co/3sT7C2N

**Controller**

```php
public function Add_slider(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'select_image'  => 'required'
    ]);

    $content = new Sliders;

    if($request->file('select_image')) {
        $content->slider_image = Storage::disk('')->putFile('slider', $request->select_image);
    }

    $check = Sliders::create(
        $request->only(['slider_image' => $content])
    );

    return back()
    ->with('success', 'Image Uploaded Successfully')
    ->with('path', $check);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload the file itself or just the filename?

Comment: I am trying to upload image file into database

Comment: @Zubair Where is your code to save image in the database?

Comment: You're storing the file in the `Storage` you want to **store** the image in the database as well? Or You want to store the file in the Storage and keep the file path in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do with the following way:

```
public function Add_slider(Request $request)
{
     $this->validate($request, [
         'select_image'  => 'required'
     ]);
     $image = $request->file('select_image');         
     $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
     Storage::disk('public')->put($image->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($image));
     $content = new Sliders;
     if($request->file('select_image'))
     {
         $content->slider_image = $image->getFilename().'.'.$extension;;
         $content->save();         

         $check = Sliders::where('id', $content->id)->select('slider_image')->get();
         return back()->with('success', 'Image Uploaded Successfully')->with('path',$check);
     }
}
```

And in view blade file:

```
<img src="{{url($path[0]->slider_image)}}" alt="{{$path[0]->slider_image}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns only the filename:

```
Storage::disk('')->putFile('slider', $request->select_image);
```

Use this instead:

```
Sliders::create([
    'slider_image' => $request->file('select_image')->get(),
]);
```

Make sure the column type from database is binary/blob.